# Laravel 5 error Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::Test

Tags: php, list, laravel, eloquent

I get the following error while trying to retrieve a array list which we use to load into the view to create a select list.

Error:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::albums

In our controller we are using following:

```
$albums = \Auth::user()->albums->lists('name', 'id');
```

And in model Albums.php we are using:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * App\Models\Albums
 *
 */
class Albums extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'albums';
}
```

In in our main file:

```
public function albums()
{

    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Albums', 'name', 'id');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is \Auth::user() object does not have albums function

The albums() function must be created in User model class

Comment: Do you example on how to do that?

Comment: \Auth::user() return Auth model object. 
In config/auth.php, you can config Auth model (User model is default). 
You should view http://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication for details

Answer (score -1):

After searching around, i have solved it by adding the following to the User() class.

```
public function albums() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Media');
}
```